# Input não está aparecendo checado

Tags: html, html5, input

Eu tenho um `input` do qual segundo o dado do usuário em sua `session` ele vem marcado ou não. O problema é que mesmo o `input` tendo a propriedade `checked="checked"`, ele não vem marcado.

**Código do `input` juntamente com a `div` da qual ele está:**

```
<div class="no-message">
      <input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0" style="display: none;" class="arredondado" <?php if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1) echo 'checked="checked"' ?> /> 
      <label for="isgift0"><?php echo $this->__("I do not want to send a message") ?></label>
 </div>
```

Nesse `label` contém um código que `CSS` que usa uma imagem por cima do `input` como se fosse o mesmo, mas isso não interfere em nada na funcionalidade.

**Códgio `CSS`:**

```
input[type="radio"].arredondado:not(checked) + label:before {
    content: "...";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -2px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: url(../../images/icons.png) no-repeat -53px -529px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 23px;
    color: transparent;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi este problema simplesmente fazendo uma verificação com `jQuery`, juntamente com `php` no carregamento da página, e assim, segundo o dado do usuário em sua sessão, atribuindo o através do `.prop()` a propriedade checado ao `input`.

**Código do `script`:**

```
<script>
    $j(document).ready(function () {
    <?php 
       if(Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1) {
    ?>
       $j('#isgift0').prop('checked','checked');
    <?php
       }
    ?>
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ele está como display none e você pode trocar para um if ternário ficando assim:

```
<input type="radio" id="isgift0" name="isgift" value="0"
       class="arredondado" <?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getInputMensagem() == 1 == 1 ?  'checked="checked"' : ''?> />
```

css:

```
 input[type="radio"].arredondado:not(checked) + label:before {
        content: url(icon2.png);
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: -2px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: 10px;
        width: 22px;
        height: 23px;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
        border: none !important;
    }
```

Comment: Não deu certo não, o `input` continua a não vir checado... e nem é a questão do `display: none`, pois tenho uma `label` que contém um `before` no `CSS` com uma imagem referente ao `input`. Inspecionando o código e dando um `display: block` no `input`, ele não vem checado.

Comment: Tenta editar a pergunta então com mais detalhes, aí tento ajudar

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com algumas informações a mais.

Comment: Ainda sim tá meio confuso pra mim, porém coloquei a imagem ao invés do background no content e retirei a cor, vou editar ali como deixei a classe, porém não sei se está correto, se quiser posta o css todo. pra ver se não tem nada sobreescrevendo.

Comment: Creio eu que o erro não seja de `CSS`, pois mesmo o `input` vindo com a propriedade `checked="checked"`, ele não vem checado.